# How do I add custom text and set custom image on Facebook Login Button for Android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Android Sdk 4.0 and have successfully implemented login with facebook. I want my custom image for login button but want use existing functionality of default login button. How do I achieve it?

I am adding sample code here.

Button:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Setting text with *loginButton.setText("CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK")* does not work too.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends");
   loginButton.setFragment(this);
   loginButton.setText("CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK");

   loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the text if you do it in the xml layout and you can set a drawable to it:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="WHATEVER YOU WANT IT TO BE"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook"/>
```

Then you can just create a drawable and do whatever you want. Example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#4e69a2"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dip"
                android:color="#4e69a2" />
            <padding android:left="0dip"
                android:top="0dip"
                android:right="0dip"
                android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#3b5998"/>
            <stroke android:width="3dip"
                android:color="#3b5998" />
            <padding android:left="0dip"
                android:top="0dip"
                android:right="0dip"
                android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. It shows "CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK" on android studio xml preview but when I run the project, it shows "Log in With Facebook" by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
fb:com_facebook_login_text="Your Text"
```

Comment: You should add some text to clarify your answer. Just a code example is not an especially good answer

Comment: Please add come comment so that any one can understand your code. Thanks.

Comment: Add `xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
fb:com_facebook_login_text="Your Text"` to your XML and it would work